# "Thickness" doesn't work in Parametric3D

Tags: plotting

I have Mathematica 8 and for some reason, the parameter "thickness" doesn't work in Parametric3D, it works in 2D very fine

> ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, -t}, {0, t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
>    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Thickness[100]}]

Anyone know a remedy for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want different colours but the same thickness then you can set the thickness with `BaseStyle`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, -t}, {0, t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}]
```

...otherwise

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, -t}, {0, t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[15]}, {Orange, 
    AbsoluteThickness[5]}}]
```

or (probably better)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, -t}, {0, t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[15]], Directive[Orange, 
    AbsoluteThickness[5]]}]
```

BTW, what is happening when you have `PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Thickness[100]}` is that your first bunch of data is styled blue, your second bunch of data is styled orange and your third bunch of data is styled "mega-thick" ...but you don't have a third bunch of data. So if you try this instead

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, -t}, {0, t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[1], Orange}]
```

now the second lot of data is styled thick. etc.

Comment: Good points. I guess he could use `Directive` as well.

Comment: yes he could also use `Directive` and is probably the preferred way rather than lists

Comment: I got a huge black cylinder when I used "ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, -t}, {0, t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[1], Orange}]"

Comment: @jak exactly -- that was the point of the exercise. Your second set of data is now styled "mega-thick" (but not orange). ...If you are surprised by how thick that was you should read the docs for `Thickness`

Comment: Yes, please use Directive to combine styles.